# Publishing gradle sub-project artifacts using a commons project

Tags: gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

Consider the following project structure:

```
app
|_subprojA
|   |_build.gradle
|_subprojB
|   |_build.gradle
|_settings.gradle
```

settings.gradle

```
include 'subprojA'
include 'subprojB'
```

build.gradle (subprojA)

```
...
dependencies {
...
}
```

build.gradle (subprojB)

```
...
dependencies {
  compile project(':subprojA')
}
```

Run `./gradlew subprojA:uploadArchives` and `./gradlew subprojB:uploadArchives`

another project, try importing `com.abc:subprojB:x.y.z` complains that `subprojA` is not available in any repo.

What I want: in my local i want subprojB to point to the local subprojA for ease in development but while publishing subprojB to artifactory i want it to create a transitive dependency on `com.abc:subprojA:x.y.z`.

Comment: How are you publishing the libraries?

Comment: using `maven` plugin
```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "") {
           authentication(userName: "", password: "")
        }
 pom.version = version
 pom.artifactId = "subprojA"
 pom.groupId = "com.abc"
```